# how to parse json result from sharepoint to show list names

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

This is the first time I work with JSon, so pls dont be rude with me :)

I have this website.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164022(v=office.15).aspx

and this javascript sample:

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: http:// site url/_api/web/lists,
type: "GET",
headers: {
"ACCEPT","application/json;odata=verbose",
"Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken
},
})
```

The thing is I have a div called results and I would like to show the list names that the rest service returns me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly how to show the list in your div without knowing how the returned JSON is formatted.  But the main idea is that you'll need to add a success callback function to your jQuery.ajax() call in which you parse the returned data and insert it into your div.  For example:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://siteurl/_api/web/lists",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "ACCEPT","application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var listTitle = data.title; // just an example; not sure if this property exists in your data
        $("$myDiv").append('<p>' + listTitle + '</p>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

See jQuery official documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

There are a lot of examples.

**EDIT**

If your call return one serializable object you can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: http:// site url/_api/web/lists,
   type: "GET",
   headers: {
      "ACCEPT","application/json;odata=verbose",
      "Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken
   },
   success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, elem){
        //... do some work where ...
        alert(elem);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to DIY with what they've shown you and get specific data.

Comment: JSON isn't uniform. A property can be another object, a string, a number, an array, etc...

Comment: Show us what are you return from the ajax call and we can be more specific in answer

Comment: how can I know what data and its format would be?, debuggin in IE? fiddler?

Comment: Maybe this asnswer is too late for you and your problems is solved yet. The "data" can be whatever you want. Sample JSON string `{ "id": "0001", "type": "donut", "name": "Cake",
 "ppu": 0.55,
 "batters":
  {
   "batter":
    [
     { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
  
     { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
    ]
  },
 "topping":
  [
   { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
   { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" }
  ]
}`